# Reinstalling Windows 11 after LFS 11.2 has been built

Tags: windows, lfs

I have my Product ID ready at hand. So, how would I install Windows 11 Home after I build LFS 11.2? I haven't started building yet... since I needed to be prepared for installing Windows 11 without destroying LFS 11.2, and also, I will have to install the Win11 ISO after the build (I have reasons). Thank you for reading this post and trying to help me.

Comment: Any system that came with Windows 11 will have product ID in the UEFI. You do not actually use it. You need to have both installs in UEFI boot mode on gpt partitioned drive. Windows wants multiple drives, so best to let it create the partitions it wants. It will use an existing ESP - efi system partition. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Comment: So can I just shrink some free space, install Windows, go into /boot/grub/grub.cfg, enable os-prober, and put grub as the first in the BIOS boot order?

Comment: If everything goes correctly yes. But you always want good backups, just in case. Windows will need bitlocker & fast start up turned off for grub/os-prober to be able to find it.

Comment: BitLocker is off, and since when installing Arch, os-prober detected it, I'm sure Fast Startup must be disabled. But I will check it out, just in case.

Comment: Windows updates may turn fast start up back on. So later if issues you may have to directly boot Windows from UEFI and turn it off again. Grub only boots working Windows, so if fast start up on, or it needs chkdsk, grub will not boot it.